# jQuery add CSS into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable with some html

```
var myvar = '<div id="myid">something here</div>';
```

How can I add some css inline to that variable like:

```
$(myvar).css("border","1px solid red");
```

If this possible?

Comment: What you will do with that result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine

```js
var myvar = '<div id="myid">something here</div>';

myvar = $(myvar).css({
  "border":"1px solid red",
  "color": "blue"
}); 

$(myvar).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but if you want to apply css using your `id` selector you need to append the `myvar` to DOM FIRST

```js
var myvar = '<div id="myid">something here</div>';
$(myvar).appendTo("body");
myvar = $("#myid").css({
  "border":"1px solid red",
  "color": "blue"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

After applying css get `outerHTML` property of dom object. Use of **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** and **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** depends your markup.

```js
var myvar = '<div id="myid">something here</div>';
myvar = $(myvar)
  //get element with id
  .filter('#myid')
  // apply css ,                   
  .css("border", "1px solid red")
  // go back to previous selector and get dom object  
  .end()[0]
  // get outerHTML property of dom object
  .outerHTML;

console.log(myvar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

or generate a temporary div and apply string as html property and then find the id inside, after get markup of temporary div

```js
var myvar = '<div id="myid">something here</div>';
// generate div with html content as string
myvar = $('<div/>', {
    html: myvar
  })
  // get id element from it
  .find('#myid')
  // apply css
  .css("border", "1px solid red")
  // go back to previous selector
  .end()
  // get html content of temporary div
  .html();

console.log(myvar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to add the inline style to the id myid as there's other div's in the string that I might want to target